# Animating newly appended element in React.js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a react component, which uses ReactCSSTransitionGroup for CSS transitions and I've got my server up and running with a dummy database and an API call that returns an array of objects and then for testing purposes, I use setTimeout to query my api url:

```
var ReactCSSTransitionGroup = React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup;

var ItemsList = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            items: [],
            api: {
                getItems: '/api/items'
            }
        }
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        this.fetchData();
    },

    fetchData: function() {
        $.get(this.state.api.getItems, function(data) {               
            this.setState({
              items: data
            });
            setTimeout(this.fetchData, 3000);
        }.bind(this));
    },

    render: function() {
        var items = this.state.items.map(function(item, index) {
            return (
                <div className="title" key={index}>                                             
                    {item.title}                    
                </div>
            );
        }.bind(this));
        return (
            <div className="content">
                <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example">
                    {items}
                </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
            </div>      
        );  
    }
});

React.render(
    <ItemsList />,
    document.querySelector('.react')
);
```

And here's the CSS:

```
.example-enter {
   opacity: 0.01;
}

.example-enter.example-enter-active {
   opacity: 1;
   transition: opacity 2.5s ease-in;
}

.example-leave {
   opacity: 1;
}

.example-leave.example-leave-active {
   opacity: 0.01;
   transition: opacity 2.5s ease-in;
}
```

What I want to achieve is that every single time an item is added to an array, I want it to animate in, BUT with one condition - new item has to appear at the top of the list.

So I do `orderBy created_at DESC` in PHP and it returns all the objects successfully (in the order that I want), but React.js renders the new object at the top and then animates the very last element (even though it added a new one at the top).

What am I doing wrong? :(

Answer (score 6):

Figured it out!

I had to do

```
<div className="title" key={item.id}>                                             
     {item.title}                    
</div>
```

instead of:

```
<div className="title" key={index}>                                             
     {item.title}                    
</div>
```

Because `index` comes from an array and it changes everytime an element is added.

Comment: Make sure your item.id is unique but I'm sure it is ;)